# Is that true that the sum of cubes of n different positive integers can equal a cube for any n>2?

Tags: number-theory

I know that the sum of cubes of three different positive integers can equal a cube (for example 3, 4, 5). The sum of cubes of four different positive integers also can equal a cube. I also saw another examples when the sum of cubes of n different positive integers was a cube. Is that true for any n>2? I mean, is that true that the sum of cubes of n different positive integers can equal a cube for any n>2?

Comment: Yes. Just multiply the examples with 3 or 4 cubes suitably and use a multiple of $6^3 = 3^3 + 4^3 + 5^3$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.